# Trying to understand in Python 3.7 how to get a number returned from a function to the main program

Tags: python, function, return, command

In general terms, I cannot get any function to return a value inside a variable (an integer, back to the main program. I have included the variable name as one of 2 arguments in the function (in this case mod_stone_value), and am using the return command to hopefully return that integer value to the main program, where that value is then added to a total value.

The key lines of code in the function would be:

```
def calc_real_stone_value(base_stone_value, mod_stone_value):

return mod_stone_value
```

and then, back in the main program:

```
total_stone_value = total_stone_value + mod_stone_value
```

The variable total_stone_value ends up being 0, yet non-zero values of mod_stone_value do print inside the function. I know I am doing something fundamentally wrong, but have no idea what it is.

Comment: If you provide a full code sample, it's gonna be easier to help you.

Comment: You can get the returned value from a function by calling the function and assigning the result to a variable, e.g. `value = calc_real_stone_value(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Using your code as a template, here is an example that illustrates passing a value from "inside" the function to the outer level (here, the outermost level of the program). I would recommend reading this part of the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) (or from the [beginning](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if it does not make sense) as it describes concepts (e.g. global vs. local variables) that are relevant to your problem.

```
c = 0
d = 5 
e = 2

def foo(a, b):
    # insert whatever code here
    d = 10 
    print(f"Inside foo(), d has value {d}")
    # to match your example
    return b

# c has the value 0, d has the value 5 
print(f"(c, d) has the value ({c}, {d})") 

# call function and pass return value to c 
c = foo(d, e)

# c has the value 2, d has the value 5 
print(f"(c, d) has the value ({c}, {d})")
```

By the way, regarding your code, statements inside the body of the function should be indented. This includes the `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks Oda. Between your example and Zack's explanation I believe I know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the number value returned by the function `calc_real_stone_value` and are confused as to why it is not changing after you call your function which supposedly "updates it's value".

The fundamental thing you are misunderstanding is that primitive data types (double, int, char, etc.) are passed by value, not by reference. Therefore, if you make changes to the local variable `mod_stone_value` within the function, the changes will not show in the variable that exists outside the function. If you want to use the value you are returning with the line `return mod_stone_value` you need to call the function with the variables you want to be used in the calculations and then assign that value to a variable (`mod_stone_value` in this case).

**Example:**

```
base_stone_value = 1
mod_stone_value = 4


def calc_real_stone_value(base_stone_value, mod_stone_value):
    # calculations
    # e.g. add the two integer arguments
    mod_stone_value += base_stone_value
    return mod_stone_value

# print the values for mod_stone_value
print(mod_stone_value)
# call function and assign value to mod_stone_value
mod_stone_value = calc_real_stone_value(base_stone_value, mod_stone_value)
print(mod_stone_value)
```

**Output:**

```
4
5
```

**Conclusion:**

Primitive variables are passed by value and in order to retrieve the value from a function that returns an integer for example, it needs to be re-assigned.

To reduce confusion, you can avoid using variable names that *shadow* variable names from an outer scope.

Comment: Thanks Zack. I am indeed doing two things wrong. I am trying to export the variable mod_stone_value from the function to the main program. The way you have explained it, I understand now Python does not work that way. The other thing I am doing wrong, and this may be more style, is trying to use the same variable name outside and inside the function. I can, and will label mod_stone_value to anything inside the function. I really only need the argument base_stone_value imported into the function, as mod_stone+value has a zero value to start with.